# What are the most over-saturated iPhone App category/markets?

Tags: sales, apple, iphone, mobile, marketing

I'm considering learning iPhone development and Objective C but don't want to avoid developing something for the most saturated markets and app categories.

What categories should I avoid?  Are there too many dating applications, or should I just stick to coming up with a creative game or two?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to know what's on the App Store, *look at the App Store*.

I don't think you are going to produce good work if you start by asking yourself, "What should I *not* do?"

Come up with a few ideas for apps, then search the App Store for them. If you find a dozen apps already there, you can avoid that category. (Unless you think you can do something much better than what's already there.) Then you can make your plans based on the search results.

Comment: +1 for "do something much better". Finding an empty market isn't the only way to success.

Comment: True, but marketing is such a pain in the ass.

Comment: I don't own an iPhone. Can you search the App Store via the web? I have found 'the App Store' but it isn't clear to me if it is (roughly) the same experience as on the iPhone.

Comment: I *think* you can search via Apple's website, but I'm not sure. You can *definitely* see everything if you install iTunes and search the store.

Answer (score 3):

The iOS market has way to many apps in general. Try to make an iPad app. There are less iPad apps out than iPhone/iPod touch.

Alternatively, try to make something for a particular (local) business.
That way you are guaranteed to get paid (by the business) and you get an app out there that is unique.

Games are always good, provided that the gameplay attracts people. Like the speakers at the WWDC 2010 said, watch play testers as they do their thing. It helps a lot with your game development.

Comment: Perhaps this should be its own question, but I'm worried that a local app will be rejected by Apple censors. Is that a legitimate fear? (Let's assume the app follows technical guidelines and isn't offensive. Just has a small market.)

Comment: There are no guarantees, but I don't think a small market will keep an app out of the store. They are more likely to be concerned with whether the app is useful.

Comment: @MichealEaster - No Worries, I've got religious oriented apps and my market is fairly small.

Comment: @benzado, not saying the app will be rejected, just won't be useful.

Comment: I was replying to the previous comment, by Michael.